# Is it possible to move last modified files using ls, tail and mv?

Tags: linux, find, ls

I want to move the last 3 modified files from a directory using bash commands. However, I noticed that I can use `find` in the following way:

```
find . -type f -mtime -0.5 -print -exec mv {} /home/user/Desktop \;
```

But I haven't figured out how to do the same with `ls -tr | tail -n 3`. For example, this doesn't work:

```
ls -tr | tail -n 3 -exec mv {} /home/user/Desktop             
tail: invalid option -- 'e'
```

The only reason I'd prefer to use the second option is in order to specify a number of files instead of an approximate time. Is it possible to make it work with `ls` and `tail`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `xargs`, as `tail` doesn't have a native ability to execute a program.

The full command would be:

```
ls -tr | tail -n 3 | xargs -I{} mv {} /home/user/Desktop
```

Breaking it down:

- `ls -tr` lists files sorted by modification date/time (`-t`).
  The most recent are first, by default; it's reversed
  (most recently modified files last) if you add `-r`.
- `tail -n 3` filters it down to the last three entries.
- `xargs -I{} mv {} /home/user/Desktop` runs `mv {} /home/user/Desktop` for each line received from `tail`. Note that the `{}` is replaced by the output from `tail`.

Note that you may need to escape the curly brackets in the call to `xargs`.

```
xargs -I\{\} mv \{\} /home/user/Desktop
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, your suggestion was my first option but I wasn't too pleased with it because I didn't understand why I need to use the curly brackets next to -I. Do you know why?

Comment: You need to specify a placeholder. By default, `xargs` appends all arguments to the command. You need to insert each argument into a seperate command, in the middle. This requires the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the names on the files, a solution relying on the output of `ls` might be problematic.  Using zsh, one could rely on globbing flags to get the job done:

```
mv *(.om[1,3]) ${somewhere}
```

The ‘magic’ is between the two parentheses after the `*`:

- `.` only selects plain files;
- `om` sorts the results of the glob by mtime;
- `[1,3]` selects the first three results

I’m aware that the question specifically asks for a bash solution, so strictly speaking this answer won’t qualify.  I’m posting it nonetheless for others who might have similar tasks and can use other shells.

Comment: To your suggested edit of the other answer http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/301337 ------ Yes, `ls` by default arranges the files in columns but only if its output goes to a terminal. Compare: `ls` and `ls | cat`.